# How to name an element of a list based on its values using if statement in R

Tags: r

### My Problem in short

Suppose I have a list of two vectors each with `6` element.

I would like to compare the values of these two vectors using `if` statement. Then, after that, I would like to assign a name for each element based on the result of the `if` statement.

### Example:

```
 x <- c(1,3,5,22,78,56)
 y <- c(2,4,3,21,88,77)
 z <- list(x, y)
```

Then, I would like to compare the value of `x` and `y` as follows:

Compare the first element of `x` with the first one of `y`. If the value of `x` is larger than `y` then, the first element should be named as `A` otherwise it should named as `B`. Then, the output should be `6` elements as follows:

```
B B A A B B
```

### Here is my try:

```
for(i in 1:6){
  if(z[[1]][i] > z[[2]][i])
    z[[1]][[i]] <- "M"
  else "B"
}
```

but return me a list.

Comment: Here is one option `Reduce(function(x,y) ifelse(x>y,'A','B'), z)`

Comment: Another option: `c("B", "A")[do.call(\`>\`, z) + 1]`

Comment: A mix of the previous comments, `LETTERS[Reduce(">", z) + 1L]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'best' solutions in R often use vectors rather than loops. The previous examples use vectors. Here's another such solution:

```
ifelse(z[[1]] > z[[2]], "A", "B")
```

If you take advantage of naming elements in a list, this example might make the code more user-friendly. In this example the names in the list are chosen to be identical to the variable names. They can be any syntactically valid name. And quotation marks aren't needed around the names in the `list()` function.

```
  z <- list(x = x, y = y)
  ifelse(z$x > z$y, "A", "B")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have a particular reason why you want to use and 'if' statement and a list, but if you're just looking for the result in a column, this works:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
x = c(1,3,5,22,78,56),
y = c(2,4,3,21,88,77)
) %>% 
  mutate(result = case_when(
    x > y ~ "A",
    TRUE ~ "B"
  ))
```

the `case_when` is often a good substitute for an if statement, and run faster too.

If you really want the result in a list, you could do this at the end:

`df_list <- list(df$x, df$y, df$result)`, but in that case the comment above probably offers a more direct solution.